# How to log and replay user interface actions?

Tags: android

Is there a way to log all user interface actions for a given application, and then replay them automatically?

Comment: Yes, but mostly with third party record and replay tools like : http://www.gorillalogic.com/monkeytalk

Comment: thanks. Any other suggestions?